# Swift - pick image and label for UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

right now I have a collectionView in which I can add cells by tapping the "addCell".

[image] [image]

My goal is that if the user taps the "addCell" a view should appear where the user can type in a title for the cell and select an image like so:

[image]

**Any idea on how I could realize that?**

```
class ContentCell: UICollectionViewCell {
let testImage: UIImageView = {
    let v = UIImageView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .cyan
    return v
}()

let testLabel: UILabel = {
    let v = UILabel()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.text = "Test Label"
    v.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next-Bold", size: 18)
    v.textColor = .darkGray
    v.textAlignment = .center
    return v
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() -> Void {

    contentView.addSubview(testLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(testImage)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        testImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        testImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        testImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        testImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:150),

        testLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testImage.bottomAnchor,constant: 1),
        testLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
        testLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        testLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
    ])
}
```

}

Comment: is that your whole code?

Comment: Google "iOS event communication such as delegate"

Comment: delegate call back to the viewController, pop up a modal to gain the required info, then create the cell.

Comment: @hecroge that is just the code for me cell that should be customisable in the end

Comment: can you post your whole code?

Comment: @hecroge do you have anything specific that you want to know? my whole code is pretty messy and its a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` you present the view controller to ask for the image image and title, and then in that view controller you declare a delegate or completion handler that when the user presses "done" or "save" in the view controller where they selected the image and title, the delegate or completion handler is then called and then tells the original view controller with the cells to add the item you just create and reload the collectionView. this is pretty standard stuff and this same pattern you'll need to learn how to use since most apps use this this same pattern 100s of times per app. i can show you from Objective-C but won't waste my time showing this is Swift. lmk if you need more help. good luck

oh yes, and for future reference, it's best to stick with delegation since using completion handlers gets very tricky when you encounter cases with nested completions and still need to maintain a weakified then strongified reference to the controller. after two degress of weakifying and strogifying "self" the system will start to randomly deallocate your controllers. Stick with delegation.

Comment: alright, definitlly need to watch some tutorials on this topic. Right now I don't have a `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`function for my `UICollectionView``

Comment: could you have a look at my latest question? I Have a pop up screen with a `textfield` now but I don't really get how I can link the `textfield` to my `cell`

Comment: @Chris maybe i just link to you the same thing but in objective-c and you get the idea. i won't write this in swift, don't have time. ill link it to you later from my own code so you see how to manipulate any field type from textfields to UISwitches in collectionviewcells and track their data so it stays where it is should given the cell resuse requirements by apple. there's not a good source for this so this would be helpful for anyone. ill do this later